# Java: Cant assign values to an instance variable in a condition statement inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I have a set of 'instance' 'variables' and i want to assign it values inside a 'loop'.
The 'loop splits' a 'string' into an 'array', does a type check and assigns its values to individual instance variables 'declared' in the class.
This is how the code looks like:

```
/******* PROCESSING THE XFILES PARAMTER TO GET THE STRINGS ***********/
        if(xfileCount>0){
            // Setting variable
            String[] xFileSplit;
            String xfName="";
            String xfValue="";
            int counti=0;
            // We start processing
            for(String fileData:xfileArray){
                // WE FURTHER BREAK X FILES
                xFileSplit=fileData.split(":");
                // Now lets get values
                xfName=xFileSplit[0];
                xfValue=xFileSplit[1];
                counti++;
                System.out.println(counti);
                // NOW LETS CHECK TO ASSIGN
                if(xfName=="indexDir"){
                    // Assign values
                    indexPath=xfValue;
                }
                else if(xfName=="docDir"){
                    // Assign values
                    docPath=xfValue;
                }
                else if(xfName=="nio"){
                    // Assign values
                    nio=Integer.parseInt(xfValue);
                }

            } // End of loop
        } // End of count check
```

The problem is that in looping the string array to assign values to individual instance variables, i keep getting null for the string type and 0 for the integer type and this is because the values wasn't assigned to the public variables in the loop.
Please i need a help with this, if any any body has ran into this kind of issue.

Comment: if(xfName=="indexDir"){

Comment: Test String equality with `String.equals`, not `==`